# Where can i find contribution graphs in Azure DevOps

Tags: github, azure-devops, commit

[image]

Im using Azure repos and where can i find graphs like github in azure devops ?

Comment: There is not a graph available on Azure Devops. This functionality is specific to github service and not all the source control providers that exist. As a result only if the company has implemented such thing, you can have it on the source control page. In my knowledge there is not such a graph for Azure DevOps repositories.

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a reminder of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6):

After installing the [Contributions Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.contributions) extension, you can go to any project on Azure DevOps -> Boards -> Contributions Graph

[image]

Comment: Currently, (February 2024) this extension is not maintained anymore. Be aware of this before installing it. https://github.com/ostreifel/vsts-contributions/issues/86

Answer (score 3):

> Im using Azure repos and where can i find graphs like github in azure devops ?

Just as GeralexGR said, this functionality is specific to github service and there is not such a graph for Azure DevOps repositories.

But you could use the extension [Contributions Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.contributions) on the marketplace, which also allows you to select one or more repositories.

[image]

Comment: We have this installed. How do you find/open it on DevOps? Where can I find this extension?